# Kif's species making it into space

Tags: futurama, aliens, space

How did Kif's species make it into space?

As we see from their planet, it is ravaged with plants.  Kif's species doesn't even have supreme control over the planet, their babies still get attacked by other animals.

We don't see any ships or any technology Kif's species has.  So how did they make it into space?  Their planet isn't even industrialized.

Comment: Kidnapping!!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have seen less than ten miles of Kif's home world, Amphibios 9. We can determine almost nothing from the planet we are shown in that episode "Kif Gets Knocked Up a Notch."

He said this particular swamp was where his ancestors went to and spawned their young. He didn't say there weren't other places on the planet where industry and technology were being sustained, perhaps in better harmony with the environment than Humans do on their planets.

For all we know, their civilization may be completely underwater which would not be visible from space at all. Nor is it know how it is that Kif ever truly became part of the Earthican Defense Force working for Zapp Brannigan.

Comment: Read your notes. The first sentence may have been insulting in YOUR opinion. But it was not meant as an insult, and I am surprised you would take it that way. Have I made it a habit of insulting other writers in my previous pieces? If the questioner was insulted, I am sorry and meant no disrespect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe humans or some other alien species visited earlier that planet and showed Kif's people on Amphibios 9 the way of traveling through universe :) Or some scenario similar to this.